# Defining pipelines of functions when passing a main argument across multiple functions

Tags: python

Discovering sk-learn pipelines (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) made me wonder why weren't I using the same idea for any set of functions applied to a single main argument.
Based on this idea I developed the following code (Using kwargs treatment from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543357):

```
import inspect
def create_sequential_pipe(func_list):
    """
    Create a pipeline for a series of functions to be applied to a single main argument

    Args:
        func_list: List of functions
    """

    def sequential_pipe(main_arg, **kwargs):

        for func in sequential_pipe._func_list:

            func_args = [k for k, v in inspect.signature(func).parameters.items()]
            func_dict = {k: kwargs.pop(k) for k in dict(kwargs) if k in func_args}
            main_arg = func(main_arg, **func_dict)

        return main_arg

    sequential_pipe._func_list = func_list

    return sequential_pipe


def example_func_1(n, power=1):
    return n ** power


def example_func_2(n, sum=0):
    return n + sum


def example_func_3(n, divide=1):
    return n / divide


if __name__ == "__main__":

    example_pipe= create_sequential_pipe([example_func_1, example_func_2, example_func_3])

    out = example_pipe(2)
    print(out)  # 2.0

    out = example_pipe(2, power=2, sum=1, divide=5)
    print(out)  # 1.0
```

I feel I could get used to its use, but I couldn't find something similar already implemented in Python, so I feel there must be a downside I am not seeing.

I could just create a wrapper function for the pipeline of functions, but I'm not sure it would be as simple.
Is there something similar commonly used in other languages? Do you think it's obfuscates the code? Are there clear downsides to using this?

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate if I could know the reason for the downvote, so I might update the question and make it more adequate. Receiving a silent downvote isn't useful.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, you are correct, whoever down voted should have left a comment. I'm only guessing about why they down voted but there could be 2 reasons, the first is the title and the second is the question seems a little hypothetical due to the function names used. The answer to the question `What does the code do?` should be clearly stated in either the title or in a text section above the code, then follow that with your concerns about the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more ideas on improvements.

Comment: That's useful, thanks! I'll try to improve those points

Comment: I think your self-answer can safely be un-deleted - any answer that contains at least one material piece of feedback is on-topic. Also, though your question is on the precipice of being closed, I think you've done a good enough job of editing it that it's now basically on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being familiar in use of `sklearn`, there are still some Python fundamentals that can be improved:

### Superfluous comprehension

```
func_args = [k for k, v in inspect.signature(func).parameters.items()]
```

can probably be

```
func_args = inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys()
```

assuming that `parameters` has the interface of a regular dictionary. Also, since you're only using it to test membership, wrap it in a call to `set()`.

### Set intersection

If you do the above and make `func_args` a set, then this:

```
for k in dict(kwargs) if k in func_args
```

can be replaced by `set(kwargs.keys()) & func_args`.

### Non-repeatable read

There's a potential issue with your use of `pop()`. This modifies your `kwargs` in a loop. Are you sure that you want a given `kwarg` to only apply to one function in your pipe, and not all of them?

### Real tests

Convert this:

```
example_pipe= create_sequential_pipe([example_func_1, example_func_2, example_func_3])

out = example_pipe(2)
print(out)  # 2.0

out = example_pipe(2, power=2, sum=1, divide=5)
print(out)  # 1.0
```

into an actual unit test - you're already most of the way there, so you might as well.

### Variadic function

```
create_sequential_pipe(func_list):
```

is a good candidate for being turned into a variadic function, i.e. accepting `*func_list`. This will make invocation simpler in some cases, including the one you showed at the bottom - there will be no need for an inner list literal.